# Can't load vendor class symfony 2.4

Tags: php, symfony

Trying to use PHPMailer in Symfony 2.4 - just can't get it to load the class.

The file in vendor is vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMail.php, at the top of the file I have this

```
<?php

namespace vendor\PHPMail; 

class PHPMailer
{ //..etc..
```

in app/autoload.php I have

```
$loader->add(

  'vendor\PHPMail', __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPMailer'
);
```

in the controller I have

```
use vendor\PHPMail\PHPMailer;
```

...and I'm calling PHPMailer like this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

The error I get is...

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "PHPMailer" from namespace  "vendor\PHPMail"...Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

Comment: what if you use composer to load PHPmailer? It'll make sure everything is correct and then you can just use the namespace documented by PHPmailer.

Comment: it's on a shared server, I don't have console access

Comment: Temporarily solved the problem by putting the required class files in the src dir

Comment: You can run composer on your PC and upload that to the server. And maybe it all works if you just remove 'vendor' from the namespace, there is no library which uses that as the first namespace element...